Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<testu() done
I am using fast api and I above is a test setup I did in which on the route test, I want to create a background task using asyncio and it would make a POST request to my another javascript server which would return status 200 and a message and the code should proceed further and log the last print from the function.
But most of the times, after making a POST request , it never proceeds further and stuck the terminal there, and when I force quite the server using CTRL + C, it prints out this error :-
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<testu() done, defined at C:\Users\Zaid\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\src\routes\render.py:135> exception=ReadTimeout('')>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\src\routes\render.py", line 142, in testu
    response = await client.post(f"{os.getenv('PHIA_APP')}/api/users/recording", headers=headers, json=userInfo)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1892, in post
    return await self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1574, in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1661, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1689, in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1726, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1763, in _send_single_request
    response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 372, in handle_async_request
    with map_httpcore_exceptions():
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 86, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ReadTimeout

async def testu(message):
    userInfo = {"userId":"clz9o11180000g0zx3ryoe0qi","videoId":"87a","videoTitle":"Claude - August 26, 2024","videoURL":"https://DDu6b.mp4"}
    test = {"hello": "test"}
    print('Now making request to your server')
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        response = await client.post(f"{os.getenv('MY_LOCALHOST')}/api/users/recording", headers=headers, json=userInfo)
        print(f"Successfully SAVED THE USER.")
        
    if response.status_code != 200:
            print("Phia app returned error")

    print('jesus chirst peace upon python')        


@router.get("/test")
async def do(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
 
    asyncio.create_task(testu('hello'))        
  
    return {"message": "Jesus is processing!"}  

